# Passing multiple values into a one parameter in SQL Server 2008 using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[DisplayFinancialColumn] 
(

    @sectorid smallint

    )

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @sectorid_vc varchar(5)
    set @sectorid_vc = REPLACE(@sectorid,',',''',''')

    DECLARE @listStr varchar(MAX) = (select [SectorFinancialType_Desc] + ',' from SectorFinancialTypes where  CONVERT(varchar(300), SectorFinancialType_ID) in  (@sectorid_vc) for xml path(''))
    DECLARE @query varchar(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + LEFT(@listStr, LEN(@listStr)-1) + ' FROM [dbo].[Financials] where project_id = ''1096'' '

    execute(@query)
END
GO
```

But I encounter

```
Error converting data type varchar to smallint.
```

But I have converted the smallint to varchar format, so why there is still such an error?

Comment: Please provide the table structure of `SectorFinancialTypes` and `[dbo].[Financials]`

Comment: @listStr doesn't print out any value

Comment: Can you provide your table structure and your variable which you're passing to the procedure? After that, I'm promise that you'll get a working answer.

Comment: I think `CONVERT(varchar(300), SectorFinancialType_ID) in  (@sectorid_vc)` statement is semantically wrong. I You want to looking for  multiple value, then use `CHARINDEX()`, `PATINDEX()` or even `LIKE`. But You can use a CTE to convert the list of sectorids into a resultset, and after that use the `EXISTS` statement.

Comment: @sectorid = '2,3' is the variable i'm passing in

Comment: And 2,3 isn't a value? It's a concat of 2 and 3, right? And you just want do get the sectors 2 and 3 back?

Comment: "2, 3" is not smalint

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is the first line of code in your procedure:

```
SET @sectorid = REPLACE(@sectorid,',',''',''')
```

will not convert @sectorid to varchar! You define @sectorid as SMALLINT parameter so @sectorid will never become a varchar variable. Change the type of your parameter or do something like that in your procedure instead:

```
declare @sectorid_vc nvarchar(5)
set @sectorid_vc = REPLACE(@sectorid,',',''',''')
```

this will do the trick i think.

Answer (score 0):

set your query like below: Here you have change @sectorid to VARCHAR(MAX)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DisplayFinancialColumn] 
( 
    @sectorid VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    //write your procedure code here
END
GO
```

let me know, is this works for you ?

Comment: i have editedt my syntax as well based on your feedback but still got error

Comment: are you passing csv (comma separated values) input to procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@sectorID),',',''',''')
```